# Add input onClick and upload images through a React form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

How can I let the user add more input fields?

And then how to programmatically store values to an array nested on a object state?

The ideia is to let the user add inputs (type = file) to add more places. Each place must have only two photos and its address. Everytime user clicks to add a new place, two more inputs and one input for the address must be shown.

```js
export interface Data {
    client: string;
    data: string;
    photos: Place[];
}

export interface Place{
    photo_1: string;
    photo_2: string;
    address: string;
}
```

```
const [data, setData] = useState<Data>({
        client: "",
        date: Date.now(),
        photos: [],
});

function handleChange(e) {
        /* if (name === "photo_1") {
            return setData((prev) => ({
                ...prev,
                photos: [...prev.photos, { photo_1: value, photo_2: value, address: "" }],
            }));
        } */

        setData((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            [name]: value,
        }));
}

function Form() {
       return (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="inputs">
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="client">Client</label>
                        <input
                            id="client"
                            type="text"
                            name="client"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="date">Date</label>
                        <input
                            id="date"
                            type="date"
                            name="date"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Place</label>
                            <div key={index}>
                                <input
                                    type="file"
                                    name="photo_1"
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                />
                                <input
                                    type="file"
                                    name="photo_2"
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                />
                                <label htmlFor="address">Local address</label>
                                <input type="text" name="address" />
                            </div>
                        <button> // must add a copy of that div above
                            Add place
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
      )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create dynamic input fields in react and then push file in its state.

For example:

1. to create a dynamic field:

```jsx
const addMoreField = (e, index) => {
  let newData = {
    otherData: '',
    file: null
  };
  setOurState([...ourState, newData]);
}
```

2. create array in state like-

```jsx
const initialState = {
  otherData: '',
  file: null
};
const [ourState,setOurState] = useState([initialState]);
```

Try this code and let me know if it works, if you are still facing an issue just let me know. I will help you.